# Case inside 'where' section that changes the condition of an AND statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am creating a store procedure and i am wondering how can i add a case block in an Add statement inside the where statement.That case statement checks an input parameter and depending its value it will change the condition from greater that to smaller than  and of course be added to the add conditions

So a part of the query is like:

```
WHERE 
AND BM.Example1 IS NOT NULL
AND BM.Example2 IS NOT NULL
AND ( Case  When @inputParamter= 'A'  THEN   AND BM.Example < 0 ELSE And BM.Example> 0 )
ORDER BY 'SEG' ASC, 'CCY' ASC
```

So by this approach i am thinking to extract an add statement depending on the input parameter but unfortunately i keep getting syntax errors.

Is that possible?

Comment: CASE WHEN that you added is used when you check table value conditions, not passed parameters

Answer (score 2):

Yepp, just use this:

```
AND (( @inputParamter= 'A' AND BM.Example < 0) OR ( @inputParamter<>'A' AND BM.Example> 0) )
```

However, be carefull with NULL, you have to put it in the logic as a third option.

Comment: `BM.Example < 0 OR  BM.Example> 0` already discard any `NULL` value. So no additional validation is required

Comment: I mentioned that because maybe he'd like to include the null case in one of the two...cases.

Comment: again if your condition is `Example > 0` then Example is already `NOT NULL`

Comment: Oh, I see, you were thinking of Example being NULL, but I was actually thinking of @inputParamter

Answer (score 0):

here is a similar answer using case

```
AND ( Case  When @inputParamter = 'A'  AND BM.Example < 0 THEN 'Y'
            When @inputParamter <> 'A'  AND BM.Example > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END = 'Y')
```